# Issues with dimensions of batch file on my Windows 7

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have recently bought my new laptop on which I have installed some (old) software which is used for accounting. That software is made for DOS. Maximum resolution of my laptop display is 1280 x 720

When I open my software using a batch file (as I always did), the cmd window becomes stretched, especially by height which oversizes my display height and I can't see content-data of my software. Please see screen bellow

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/1147x645q90/194/kzy8.jpg

and this is how code of my BATCH file looks like:

```
PATH=C:\;C:\DLL1.9;C:\DBASE
cd..
CD mpsg
CD MP2014
DATE
MPSW
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to change the code of the batch file in order to show screen of my software in controlled size (for example 640x480).

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're running Windows on the new laptop? What version? If it's reasonably modern, you should be able to right-click on the batch file, click Properties, choose the Compatibility tab, and check the box for "Run in 640x480 screen resolution."

Comment: hello, I have already tryed that but it doesn't work. That is why I posted code of the BATCH file. Perhaps some code in BATCH file needs to be added in order to open the window as it should?

Answer (score 0):

Hit Alt and Space, then hit the M key.
Use the down arrow key to move the window so the title bar is in view.

Right click the title bar and adjust the cmd defaults so that the screen size is `80 columns x 25 lines` which should fit.

Comment: Hello, I have already tried that. What is interesting about this siftware is that when I right click the title bar there is no value Properties?? I tried all types of combinations in order to see 20% of bottom part of screen but it always stays fixed. Is is possible to change anything in BATCH file in order to show window in controlled size? BATCH file is all I can edit, it seams.

Comment: What do you see when you right click the title bar?  Show us a screen shot.  Maybe it is not a CMD window at all, if there is no `properties` entry.